# VBA - Dynamically set variable from array

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm creating a macro for Outlook that processes email items in designated folder that gets triggered by a rule. My `Sub` routine sets the sub-folder like this:

```
Set olSub = olMailbox.Folders("Customer").Folders("Requests").Folders("Open")
```

I would like to be able to use my `Sub` for many different folders, the only difference being the line above.

My question is how can I pass an array to my `Sub` that would set `olSub` with the chained `.Folders()` statement? Keeping in mind the number of sub-folders and therefore the array could vary in length.

The desired outcome would be something like this:

```
Sub MainRoutine(olArr)
    ...

    ' Some sort of magic loop that sets olSub from olArr until,
    olSub = olMailbox.Folders("Customer").Folders("Requests").Folders("Open")

    ...
End Sub

Sub OtherRoutine()
    olArr = Array("Customer", "Requests", "Open")
    MainRoutine olArr
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Function GetFolder(FromFolderPath As String) As MAPIFolder
    Dim arrPaths() As String
    arrPaths = Split(FromFolderPath, "\")

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim objLoopFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim objNS As NameSpace
    Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objLoopFolder = objNS.Folders("My Mailbox Name")

    For i = 0 To UBound(arrPaths)
        Set objLoopFolder = objLoopFolder.Folders.Item(arrPaths(i))
    Next

    Set GetFolder = objLoopFolder
End Function
```

It takes a folder path, e.g. `My Mailbox Name\First Folder\Sub Folder 1\Sub Folder 2`, but if you really need it to take an array, you can easily modify it.